# To run all test cases by invoking driver once for a suite

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium2, testng

I want to run all my test cases with one start up and tear down process. I have written code for multiple browser testing and as of now I am repeating those codes in every class file under @BeforeMethod to run my test cases present in that class.

But I want to write them once and execute all my test cases with it. Is it possible to do so?

I have tried with different annotations but nothing worked for me. I am probably not writing it in perfect manner. I have also given @Data Providers for inputs.

Is it I am making it complex? Or we can do all those things in one run.

Kindly suggest.

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet please? It would be helpful to understand how the current structure is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
class Hull {

    protected WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeMethod 
    public void initializeDriver() {
        // Initialize the driver here.
    }
}

class ClassWithTestMethods extends Hull {
    // Test methods with @Test annotation.
    // Use the driver variable of Hull in the test methods.
}
```

The `initializeDriver` method should always be executed before each test method.

Currently I do not know how you use the data providers. But it should work if you define it in the `Hull` class too.

A `@BeforeSuite` annotation also exists.

Comment: I was doing the same thing but was getting some exception. I finally resolved them. With your answer I became sure that whatever I was trying is correct.Thanks.